# Externally configurable filtering using Java lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-8, java-stream

Lets say I have an external JSON as:

```json
[{
    "condition": "equals",
    "field": "name",
    "value": "jack"
  },
  {
    "condition": "greater",
    "field": "age",
    "value": 25
  }
]
```

What this means is I want to check, in a list of Person objects for people with name as `"jack"` and `age > 25`. It is fairly simple with Java 8 filtering(example shown is filtering just on name).

However, I want to make this filter configurable and also apply multiple filters. Assuming the Person pojo below (which is self-explanatory), takes name and age, how can I make the filters dynamic or configurable?

```java
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // Accessors and Mutators
}
```

```java
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
    new Person("mkyong", 30),
    new Person("jack", 20),
    new Person("lawrence", 40)
);

Person result1 = persons.stream()            // Convert to steam
    .filter(x -> "jack".equals(x.getName())) // we want "jack" only
    .findAny()                               // If 'findAny' then return found
    .orElse(null);
```

I am expecting a list of Person object which satisfy the criterion as a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That has little to do with `streams` per-se as far as I can tell. That filter method is just a `Predicate` which can be supplied as an instance, for example from a factory method that you could create.

```
static Predicate<Person> fromName(String value){
    return p -> p.getName().equals(value);
}
```

Suppose you have another method:

```
static Predicate<Person> fromAge(int value) {
    return p -> p.getAge() == value;
}
```

Because `Predicate.and`, `Predicate.or` exists you could do:

```
 fromAge(12).and(fromName("jack"));
```

thus chaining your predicates

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches to this.

Either you just chain call the desired filters inline:

```
Person result1 = persons.stream()
    .filter(x -> "jack".equals(x.getName()))
    .filter(x -> 25 > x.getAge()) // new filter
    .findAny()
    .orElse(null);
```

Or, you have your own class implementing `Predicate<Person>`.

In which case, you may use a builder pattern to build your predicate step-by-step.

The difficulties you'll have to face are as follows:

- Handling boolean relation between terms (`&&` vs `||`)
- Handling nested boolean relations (`(a && b) || c` is not `a && (b || c)`)

Note that `Predicate` has handy `and` and `or` methods to chain predicates.